# How can I ensure consistency between multiple model object instances

Tags: java, android, sql, model, android-sqlite

**BACKGROUND**

This is a problem I keep coming back to as I'm developing an Android application. Let's say my app lets users "follow" TV shows. My `TVShow` model class is as follows:

```
public class TVShow {
    String title;
    String[] show_cast;
    boolean currently_airing = true;
    boolean following = false;
    long nextEpisodeTime;
    String genre;
}
```

I have an SQL database that stores hundreds of TV shows. This is useful because I can leverage detailed queries to select shows based on specific information. The problem I get is when I have multiple instances of `TVShow` that represent the same show.

**EXAMPLE**

Let's say I have the TV show "The Walking Dead" in my database and I create a `TVShow` object from an SQL query. This object instance will be called `TVShow#1`. I decide to "follow" this show, so I set `TVShow#1.following = true`. Somewhere else in my app I query a list of shows that are currently airing, which "The Walking Dead" is part of. A new instance of `TVShow` will be created called `TVShow#2` for that list. The problem here is that I have two `TVShow` objects, `TVShow#1` and `TVShow#2` that represent "The Walking Dead", but they have differing values for `following`. This will cause problems throughout the logic of my application because there isn't a consistency between all `TVShow` instances that represent the same TV show.

**MY BAD WORKAROUND**

Expand this to a bunch of object instances and much more complicated fields and logic, and that is the situation I am currently in. I have mitigated this by loading all SQL data into memory (usually `ArrayList` or `HashMap`) when the app is launched, and only querying these Java objects instead of the SQL database. This solution is inefficient and inconvenient, where SQL queries could really help. I hope my examples were not too confusing. If I can clarify or provide more information, I'd be happy to. Please let me know if there is something better I can do to ensure consistency between multiple instances of the same model object.

Comment: How about saving only the instance in hashmap instead all data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I use for this problem is RxJava based, however it would be possible to implement without Rx.

The idea is that you 'subscribe' to the data from your database query.  Each time there is a write to the database which affects one of the tables your query touches then the query gets re-run and you get a fresh set of data.

This way when `TVShow1` gets saved to the database, the query which produced `TVShow2` gets re-run and you have the latest version of your data.

There are two libraries which do all of this for you if you are using Rx:

[StorIO](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio)
[sqlbrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite)

If you are not using Rx then [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/) has a similar functionality with its change adapters.

Finally you could roll your own. This would involve having a singleton which you register your queries with, linked to the tables they are reading from.  Each time you do a write you let this class know which tables have been changed and it re-runs your queries.

Comment: This sounds really interesting. I'm not currently using RxJava so I'll give Realm a look. I'm currently using SugarORM to manage SQL transactions so I'd have to look into migrating the data.